# How to extract string from CharField in class level?

Tags: django, django-models

Because I want the Charfield string to save my Image at specific folder. I want to transfer or extract the string from CharField in Django

I have tried the to_python method it doesn't work in class level.

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    cata = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to= 'ourwork/image/' + str(cata) + '/' + str(filename) , default='ourwork/default/default.png', verbose_name='图片')    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename
```

I want to see the image I uploaded at Django Admin console to show at 'ourwork/project/image' folder

Comment: This is not at all a thing you can do. But see [the docs on `upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) for the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: use a *callable* and let the callable calculate the `upload_to` attribute, based on the field of the model object.

You can use a *callable* as [**`FileField.upload_to`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), as the documentation specifies:

> `upload_to` may also be a **callable**, such as a function. This will
>   be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This
>   callable **must accept two arguments** and return a Unix-style path
>   (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system.

So we can define this as:

```
def our_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'ourwork/image/{}/{}'.format(instance.cata, instance.filename)

class Project(models.Model):
   filename = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   cata = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to=our_upload_to, default='ourwork/default/default.png', verbose_name='图片')    

   def __str__(self):
       return self.filename
```

We thus here calculate the `upload_to` parameter based on the `instance` (first parameter), and ignore the filename of that was originally given to the file by the user that uploaded the file.

Comment: Oh my god. I can never imagine that Stack overflow can be so accurate and professional. Thank you so much. It solves my problem and save my life. It works fine now.